Can I add a totals row to a summary table but with a conditional sum?
I have two columns in a data frame I want to summarize by region. I then want to add a totals row to the summary table, but the total is a count of the number rows in the summary table with a value > 0. I have to repeat this for several different data frames.
region <- c("R1", "R2", "R3", "R4", "R5", "R1", "R2", "R3", "R4", "R5")
housing <- c(0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1)
food <- c(1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1)
df <- data.frame(region,housing,food)


Using janitor's adorn_totals is close, but it sums the values for each column.
library(janitor)
df %>%
  group_by(region) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(housing:food), sum, na.rm = TRUE) %>%
  adorn_totals(where = "row", name = "Not the total I want")


sum table close
Nice, but I want to count the number of rows in each column that are greater than 0, like this:
enter image description here
I tried sum with ifelse which I couldn't get to work (like Excel countif). I can create a separate summary table and then bind_rows, but that's a lot of steps. Is there a way to use adorn_totals? Any suggestions are appreciated.

You could summarize the sums first and bind those results to a second summarize result.
library(dplyr)

summarized_df <- df |>
  group_by(region) |>
  summarise(across(housing:food, \(x) sum(x, na.rm = TRUE))) 

bind_rows(
  summarized_df,
  summarized_df |>
    summarise(region = 'Count',
              across(housing:food, \(x) sum(x > 0)))
)
#> # A tibble: 6 × 3
#>   region housing  food
#>   <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 R1           0     1
#> 2 R2           2     2
#> 3 R3           1     0
#> 4 R4           1     1
#> 5 R5           2     2
#> 6 Count        4     4


Thank you. Simple! Could you explain what the \(x) notation does in the summarise statement? I don't think I've seen that before.

Hi fernaldd. That is an anonymous function. As of dplyr 1.1.0 its the preferred way to supply arguments to functions. It is accomplishing the same thing as across(housing:food, sum, na.rm=TRUE) would.

Got it. Thank you, again, Seth.
